# Reverse Breakdown Voltage for a diode

Tags: diodes, datasheet, reverse-breakdown

Could anyone explain why is the reverse breakdown voltage measured for a general diode? Diodes work in the forward biased region. Then why is it important to know the reverse breakdown voltage?

Comment: If you subject the diode only to forward voltage, then why use a diode in the first place?

Comment: Example: suppose you drive a 24V solenoid from somewhere. Then you need to protect the driver circuit against reverse EMF, by means of a "freewheel"/"flyback" diode. The diode's cathode will then be continuously connected to 24V, so it needs to be able to handle that reverse voltage.

Comment: `Diodes work in the forward biased region.` When a diode blocks a current flow, isn't it going to be exposed to reverse voltage? Can a diode withstand infinitely high reverse voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Diodes have to work in both the forward biased and reverse biased regions. For example when used to rectify an AC waveform they are exposed to the full peak forward voltage and then in the other half cycle to the full peak negative voltage.

You have to know that the diode will withstand the negative voltage and that is why the reverse breakdown voltage specification is necessary.

[image]